# Xinc wont email me

Tags: email, phing, xinc

Do i need some configuration to make my CI xinc to email upong success failures or recoveries?
I have a clean ubuntu installation

Answer (score 0):

Phing does not complain when pear/Mail or pear/Mail_Mime are not installed. It simply does not send the email.